# Why are "weak measurements" defined via a second-order approximation of the dynamics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, quantum-information, quantum-measurements

Consider an initial (separable, pure) bipartite state $|\Psi\rangle=|\psi\rangle\otimes|\phi\rangle$, evolving with an interaction Hamiltonian $H\equiv A\otimes B$. At a time $t$, the evolves state is thus
$$|\Psi'\rangle\equiv e^{-iHt}|\Psi\rangle
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-it)^n}{n!} [(A^n|\psi\rangle)\otimes( B^n|\psi\rangle)].$$
If, after this evolution, we measure the second system and find some state $|q\rangle$, the post-measurement state on the first system is (up to normalisation):
$$(I\otimes\langle q|)|\Psi'\rangle
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-it)^n}{n!}\langle q|B^n|\phi\rangle\,\, A^n |\psi\rangle.$$
Considering only the first orders in $t$, we can write
$$(I\otimes\langle q|)|\Psi'\rangle
= \left(\langle q|\phi\rangle -it A \langle q|B|\phi\rangle - \frac{t^2}{2}A^2 \langle q|B^2|\phi\rangle\right) |\psi\rangle + \mathcal O(t^3).$$

In the context of *[weak measurements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_measurement)*, people seem to consider this type of setup, and perform the above approximation to the second order in the interaction.

Why are weak measurements/interactions defined using specifically a *second-order* approximation? Are there specific physical phenomena that would not emerge stopping at the first order? Or is there some other general way to understand why the second-order approximation is a good choice in this context?